# Alternative for googleVis in R

Tags: r, googlevis

I like googleVGis for R very much. but unfortunately a online connection is required.
is there another packages that provide similar functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see one of the following package:

1. [rCharts](http://ramnathv.github.io/rCharts/)
2. [gg2v](https://github.com/hadley/gg2v)
3. [clickme](https://github.com/nachocab/clickme)
4. [rVega](https://github.com/metagraf/rVega)